# rpc.rquotad connection refused

Tags: quota, nfs4

I setup an NFS file server using Ubuntu 15.04 to replace an aging CentOS 6 based server.  I have user quotas on the file system and on the server initially quota -v would segfault but upgrading the kernel from the 3.19.0-30 to 4.2.3 solved that.  However, under both kernels, rpc.quotad seems to be refusing the connection. I have verified that rpc.rquotad (service name quotarpc) is in fact enabled and running. I have eliminated firewall and hosts.allow being the issue.  Checking the logs I see that rpc.quotad is segfaulting under the old or new kernel.  I have read other people have solved this by going to the previous version of rpc.quotad, however I don't know how/where to obtain that.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed the version of rpc.rquotad from 14.10 and replaced the 15.04 version with it and then it worked, so the 15.04 version is broken.